# C# form custom textbox format binding

Tags: c#, data-binding, forms, textbox, format

I haev an object with a DateTime property. I want to map the time to a textbox (thus want the user enter the time, it's directly reverberated to my property).

However I just want to display the time. How can I say this (ie the format should be something like hh:mm to be correct).

Less specifcly how can I format the text "sent" to the object and the other way too ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify "HH:mm" as the binding's `FormatString`

If you need more complex formatting than what a format string can provide, you can handle the `Format` event of the binding, which enables you to provide your own formatting logic

Comment: Sounds that it is what I'm looking for however the whole datetime is displayed (daysn months etc..). I put the folowwing code :     
            textBoxHorodatage.DataBindings.Add("Text", _customObject, "HoroDate");
            textBoxHorodatage.DataBindings[0].FormatString = "hh:mm";

Comment: Bis - is there a way to retrieve the binding object in a better way than [0] ?

Comment: I should had : textBoxHorodatage.DataBindings[0].FormattingEnabled = true;

Comment: Ah oui, j'avais oublié FormattingEnabled ;). Une meilleure solution que [0] : textBoxHorodatage.DataBindings["Text"]

Comment: Merci bien. Dernière question, quand on tape un format erroné, le control n'est, bien sur, pas validé. Donc la text box garde le focus, est ce qu'il y a un event du genre : ValidateFailed or BindingFailed etc ?

Comment: Il y a un évènement BindingComplete, avec des paramètres qui peuvent t'indiquer s'il y a eu une erreur

Comment: Ok c'est encore bien ce que je cherchais, dsl mes yeux l'ont raté.

Comment: what? I dont understand any of this

Comment: @Default, sorry about that... knowing that Toto spoke French, I switched to French out of laziness ;)